# Null Pointer Exception when starting IME Preference

Tags: android, keyboard, preferenceactivity

I am using the google sample code to create a soft keyboard and i am trying to implement a settings preference that will allow me to change the style of the keys for the keyboard. When i try to call the Input method services Preference Activity (unedited from the sample code) i get a null pointer exception.

```
//show settings menu on click of menu key
ImePreferences p = new ImePreferences();
Intent i = p.getIntent();
startActivity(i);
```

Here is my ImePreference.

```
public class ImePreferences extends PreferenceActivity {

/**
 * Adds intent extras so fragment opens
 */
@Override
public Intent getIntent() {
    final Intent modIntent = new Intent(super.getIntent());
    modIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT, Settings.class.getName());
    modIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_NO_HEADERS, true);
    return modIntent;
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // We overwrite the title of the activity, as the default one is "Voice Search".
    setTitle(R.string.IME_settings);
}


public static class Settings extends InputMethodSettingsFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setInputMethodSettingsCategoryTitle(R.string.language_selection_title);
        setSubtypeEnablerTitle(R.string.select_language);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.ime_preferences);
    }
}
```

}

Here is my log

```
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3217)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at orsto.board.orstoboardv3.ImePreferences.getIntent(ImePreferences.java:19)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at orsto.board.orstoboardv3.Orstoboard.onKey(Orstoboard.java:450)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.detectAndSendKey(KeyboardView.java:824)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.onModifiedTouchEvent(KeyboardView.java:1341)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.onTouchEvent(KeyboardView.java:1204)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5553)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2019)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1754)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2019)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1754)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2019)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1754)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2019)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1754)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2019)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1754)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1930)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1389)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:738)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at android.inputmethodservice.SoftInputWindow.dispatchTouchEvent(SoftInputWindow.java:75)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1878)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5733)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3104)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2666)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.processInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:900)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2675)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
07-09 13:36:29.577: E/AndroidRuntime(19994):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any idea why this is happening this is the first time im building a keyboard as a service and it has me stumped.

Thanks
Marc

Comment: `new ImePreferences()` you can't do that. You are generally not allowed to instantiate activities.

Comment: The Preference file i pasted in is unchanged from the sample code i have to instantiate the activity to be able to use the getIntent() method.

Comment: `i have to instantiate the activity to be able to use the getIntent() method` no. you can't use `getIntent` on an activity that you have instantiated yourself.

Comment: I am quite literally following what the Softkeyboard Sample code has given me everything pasted in from ImePreferences is all sample code from the Sample project, so either i can or google is wrong :/

Comment: I don't see where `new ImePreferences()` is in the sample code?

Comment: Its never actually called in the sample code or atleast the one i can get my hands on so i had to improvise on that bit i couldn't see any other way of being able to call the getIntent method.

Comment: i still don't get why you want to call `getIntent`. You don't have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rather get your intent like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ImePreferences.class);
```

rather than:

```
ImePreferences p = new ImePreferences();
Intent i = p.getIntent();
```

where the `this` keyword refers to the current activity. It's the Android system who will then instantiate the `ImePreferences` activity when you call `startActivity(i)`.

Comment: I already tried this as well i get an error telling me im trying to start an activity that doesn't exist.

Comment: According to your error log, the original NullPointerException appeared in ImePreferences.getIntent(). Do I understand it right that you can now obtain the intent but get another error when calling startActivity(i)? And could you post that exact error log?

Comment: It is Returning null on this line `final Intent modIntent = new Intent(super.getIntent());` ill paste in the log from when i try to start the class from a normal intent

Comment: `im trying to start an activity that doesn't exist.` I assume you have declared that activity in your manifest, right?